# Shortcut for PhpStorm to jump (move cursor) to the next function parameter

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

How can I jump to next parameter in function declaration? (some keyboard shortcut)

For example:

```
public function get($model, string $key, <cursor here>$value, <jump here>$attributes)
{
    // ...
}
```

I know about <kbd>Ctrl + P</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but this works only when calling function. However I want go to the next argument on declaration.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such action in keymap settings (or I was not able to find any).
As some sort of workaround you may record a macro with the following combo: "Ctrl+Right(move to the end of current param), Right, Right" and then assign a specific key shortcut to it.

Sounds too rough, I know but that should do the trick.

Comment: How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just record a macro with this key combo:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-macros-in-the-editor.html

Then you may assign this new macro to the specific key combo (in "Keymap" settings)

Comment: Thaks for the idea! I solved this using `Ctrl+W` + `Right` + `Right` + `Right` + `Ctrl+W` + `Right`. Could you suggest a key shortcut, please? Because all what I considered are already taken.